# Can I choose what parser Spring uses to parse html files?

Tags: java, xml, spring, parsing

For now it uses `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException` parser which throws exception if theres no closing `</meta>, </link> or </input>` tag.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{../css/jquery-ui.css}">
<script th:src="@{../js/jquery-ui.js}"></script>
```

Comment: are you sure you haven't declared your html file as xhtml ?

Comment: All html files has .html prefix and "<!DOCTYPE html>" in first line.

Comment: Post your configuration here. If you're using Spring Boot, that means your POM or Gradle build file.

Comment: I don't know if this is an option in your scenario, therefore just writing this as a comment. Maybe in your case you could convert HTML to XHTML using something like `htmltidy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're actually asking about *Thymeleaf*, not Spring.

[The Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#what-kind-of-templates-can-thymeleaf-process) specifically addresses well-formedness of documents and notes that there's a mode, Legacy HTML5, that will clean up templates before feeding them to the SAX parser. Alternately, Thymeleaf 3.0, which is a ground-up rewrite, can operate on documents that are not valid XML; if you don't need a dialect that hasn't been ported (mostly Layout at this point), then 3.0 is ready for use now.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, I will try to use 3.0 version.

Comment: Unfortunately, updating library didin't helped :/

Comment: @Jurgis Then either you didn't update completely or there's configuration telling Thymeleaf to enforce well-formedness.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, there was a lot of cached libraries. Thank you